# How to harvest water passivley?

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, water, air

I have been reading recently about methods to collect moisture from the air passively and turn it into water. However, is there any attempt currently for small-scale water harvesting?

Methods I have found :

1- air well

2- Zibold's collector (building)

3- heat sinks collecter

By small scale, I am referring to the size of a cup of water. Is there a way to condense water passively (no external power source)?

(Here I am not concerned about the speed of generating water or whether the water is drinkable. I am targeting a method to condense water without supervision or external interference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all the methods you list can be run using only the heat of the sun, and no other external power source. The general term for this type of water condenser is a [solar still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_still). If you search for "solar still" on YouTube you can find instructions for making a variety of home-made designs, as well as some more sophisticated commercial products.